# How to cluster a time series using KMeans in python

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

So I have a data in the form [UID obj1 obj2..] x timestamp and I want to cluster this data in python using kmeans from sklearn. Where should I start?

EDIT:

So basically I'm trying to cluster users based on clickstream data, and classify them based on usage patterns.

Comment: Could you [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Could you give an example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503668/how-to-cluster-time-series-data-using-k-means-algorithm

Comment: sci-kit has great implementations of [k-means](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.KMeans) and other clustering algorithms

Answer (score 0):

You can add more features based on the raw data, and using methods like RFM Analysis. RFM = recency, frequency, monetary

For example:

`How often the user logged in?`

`The last time the user logged in?`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python library [Retentioneering](https://retentioneering.github.io/retentioneering-tools/_build/html/index.html) ([github](https://github.com/retentioneering/retentioneering-tools)), which allows you to cluster your users based on clickstream data with a simple command. You can also specify any target events you are interested in your clusters and explore obtained graphs using interactive graphs.

```
data.rete.get_clusters(method='kmeans',
                   feature_type='tfidf',
                   n_clusters=8,
                   ngram_range=(1,2),
                   plot_type='cluster_bar',
                   targets=['payment_done','cart']);
```

[results of user clustering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhANY.png)

Next you can explore obtained behavioral clusters with interactive graph:

```
clus_0 = data.rete.filter_cluster(0)
clus_0.rete.plot_graph(thresh=0.1,
                   weight_col='user_id',
                   targets = {'lost':'red',
                              'payment_done':'green'})
```

[graph visualization example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBbJW.png)